# Elixir phoenix strip white space from html output in render

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Does anyone know how to Strip html from whitespace with Elixir in phoenix?
I do see String.strip but I inspected what render returns, and it's not a string... and I'm considering where and how to put it here and there inside templates.. but what I really wand to accomplish is for all whitespace between html tags to be stripped out.

**Why?**
So that I can use :empty in my css  :D

**Example**

```
<div id="hide-me-if-no-content">
  <%= content, some times, this actually spans multiple lines, there's lot of content to go through (under certain conditions) and still sometimes not even one of those 3-9 items are set.  =>
</div>
```

And so I'd like to just strip whitespaces out, so that if there is nothing in there, I'd have no spaces between  without the need of movin `<%=` up next to the div, and without specifically setting a function in place here, to only run "unless any item is set, do this block..", as it's be different in different views.

Comment: I think you should just manually remove the white spaces in the `eex` templates.

Comment: That makes for terrible markup indentation.

Comment: Can you show a brief example of what you are attempting to accomplish?

Comment: Sure! Updated the question.

Comment: HTML already acts the way you expect. https://jsfiddle.net/43vsjcgr/ If there is no actual content in the tag (whitespace and newlines don't count) it will not display the div.

Comment: There is space between <div> </div> even if <%= => ends up being empty.

Comment: That space alone will not cause a div to show.

Comment: I have a feeling that this `:empty` selector is not worth all the trouble that you are about to have if you go this path.

Comment: I'm saying that yes it is.
It is all about style, and so I want to keep style there. And who doesn't want to keep documents as small as possible before eating up the recipients mobile data?

@Justin - yes it does. As in, :empty won't work on that element.

Comment: Hey. It's hard to understand what your use case is but if you really want to do this the only thing I can think of is (except just doing `<div><%= content %></div>`), is to use Floki to parse the html and then output it again using `Floki.raw_html`. So for example in your layout/app.html.eex:

`<%= render_to_iodata(@view_module, @view_template, assigns) |> Floki.parse() |> Floki.raw_html |> raw %>`

Comment: By the way if you would use a partial or a view helper the markup / line length wouldn't be too bad right?

Comment: I'll take a look at Flaki!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I properly understood the question, [`String.trim/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/String.html#trim/1) is what you are looking for:

```
iex> String.trim("     ")
""
```

While you might put it directly into your template, I would better consider producing the respected *assign* in controller/view to use it like:

```
# view
@stripped = String.trim(stuff)

# template
<%= @stripped =>
```